# How do I initialise AutoScrollPosition to something other than zero?

Tags: scroll, horizontal-scrolling

In a C# Windows Forms app, I have a Form with a Panel with a PictureBox on it. The PictureBox is twice as wide as the Panel and has a graphics drawing in it. On scaling etc. I set AutoScrollPosition to keep the section of interest in the middle of the Panel: no problem. My problem is: when the app starts I want the Panel to show a section in the middle of the drawing, rather than the left hand side.

In the Form constructor I have:

```
    panel1.AutoScroll = true;
    panel1.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(100, 0);
    textBox1.Text = panel1.AutoScrollPosition.ToString();
```

But on starting the app, the TextBox shows (0, 0) and the initial scroll position is at the left.

So, for test, I added a button which when pressed also executes:

```
    panel1.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(100, 0);
    textBox1.Text = panel1.AutoScrollPosition.ToString();
```

The TextBox then shows (100, 0) and the panel is scrolled as expected.

I makes no difference whether or not the AutoScrollPosition line is included in the constructor.
What must I do to initialise the scroll position without user interaction?

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it: you override OnLoad and set AutoScrollPosition in that, e.g.:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        int yScroll = yToCentre - panel1.Height / 2;
        panel1.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, yScroll);
    }
```